# How to test a Javascript whether a form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I am trying to test some of my javascript with Jasmine.

I am a newbie when it comes to Jasmine and my knowledge about Javascript is at best basic. What I want to do is to make sure the form is submitted. I can't figure out how the syntax for the tests should look like. I guess I need to use spyOn, but I'm not quite sure how. I would love it if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
function submitform(array) {
    var token = array[0].replace("access_token=", "");
    if ((token !== "")) {
        $('input[name=Token]').val(token);
        var frm = document.getElementById("tokenform");
        frm.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To test that `frm.submit()` was called you have to mock it. There are two ways to to it. The first way would work without code changes by spying on `document.getElementById`, this will work in your example as you only use it once, it will be harder if use `document.getElementById` more often.

```
var submit;
beforeEach(){
  // when your code calls document.getElementById it return an object 
  // with just one property where you can spy on that it was called
  submit = jasmine.createSpy();
  spyOn(document 'getElementById').andReturn({submit:submit})
}

it ("should submit", function(){
  submitform([somedata]);
  expect(submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

The better way is to rewrite your code for better testability. So instead of getting the form by calling a DOM function, inject the form into your function as an argument. Now you can just pass the mock into your function instead of mocking `document.getElementById`. This pattern is also known as [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

```
function submitform(array, frm) {
    var token = array[0].replace("access_token=", "");
    if ((token !== "")) {
        $('input[name=Token]').val(token);
        frm.submit();
    }
}

it ("should submit", function(){
  var submit = jasmine.createSpy();
  var form = {submit: submit}
  submitform([somedata],form);
  expect(submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```